# How to call different menus in header.php in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to show different menus for different templates. For example if the user is in any page i want to show one menu, if user is in post category i want to show another menu, if the user in single.php page i want to show another menu. How to do it ?

I know about creating multiple header(and these headers show different menu) in the theme and calling these header in different templates. But i want to do it simply though if else statement in my header.php itself. How to do it?

My header.php menu code is -

```
                        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                             <?php
                                wp_nav_menu( array(
                                    'menu'              => 'primary',
                                    'theme_location'    => 'header-menu',
                                    'depth'             => 2,
                                    'container'         => 'div',
                                    'container_class'   => '',
                                    'container_id'      => '',
                                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                                    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                                    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                                );
                            ?>
                        </div>
```

i want to do an if else statement in the header.php itself like -

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    if(template is page)
    {
        //menu code 1
    }
    else (template is category)
    {
        //menu code 2
    } 
</div>
```

Please help ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few functions you could try that let you know what template you are using, as you want to do it conditionally `is_page_template` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/ could be the best one for you. You can then use that to show the relevant menu if a certain template is being used. Don't forget a general else condition at the end to show a default menu :)

Comment: i checked it's not working . I placed this code in my header.php file and every time it is showing b. My code - <?php if(is_page_template())
         {
           echo "a";
                                 }   
         else 
         {
             echo "b";
         }

Comment: thanks for your help i solved it. Using is_page() will do the trick here.

Comment: You cant just use is_page_template() you need to give it some values :) then it will work. All is_page() will do is tell you that you are using a page not which template is being used. But if that has done the trick then cool.

Comment: Also is_single() works to tell you if it is just a post.